# Why didn't the lake float during the anomaly scene?

Tags: gravity-falls

In the *Gravity Falls* episode "[Not What He Seems](https://gravityfalls.fandom.com/wiki/Not_What_He_Seems)", we see a series of gravity anomalies in and around a lake.

Since it has the same density as the other objects, why didn't the water float away?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the lake was considered to be a compact mass (that means the whole lake is an object, not just a lot of water). Or this may be another error of the show like the ones listed [here](https://gravityfalls.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_goofs). We all know that the allusions of the cartoon make it more probable to human production error.